# in MongoDB, how to search in text and arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

We have db like this:

```
{
tags : ["key1", "key2", "key3", "car", "etc.."],
question : "some text here "
},
{
tags : ["bla1", "bla2", "bla3", "etc.."],
question : "My car is here"
}
```

I need query, that will get both rows with keyword "car"

I tried:

```
db.some.find(
 '$or' : [ ["tags" : "car" ], [ "$text" : [ "$search" : "car" ] ] ]
);
```

"question" is text index

Comment: I think you have syntax issues (if you're running this from the `mongo` shell).  Try this:  `db.some.find({ '$or' : [ { "tags" : "car" }, { "$text": { "$search" : "car" } } ] });`

Answer (score 3):

Unless you need to use `$text`, you can use plain `$regex`:

```
db.some.find({ $or:[ {tags:"car"}, {question:/car/} ] })
```